# Is it possible to pull data from the same cell across *all tabs* (current and future) in Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Background:**

I run an online language school, and I use Google Sheets to store each student's financial account. But having a separate sheet for each student makes accounting a nightmare (we have a lot of students and frequent activity). Starting in 2015, I want to use one master financial spreadsheet, each student with his/her own tab. This would allow me to automate a ton of admin work (projections, payroll, taxes).

**Challenge:**

I want to write a function that pulls data from the same cell in *all tabs* in the document, meaning that it would include any new tab that I add for a new student automatically. Obviously this could get sloppy if I don't keep my data exceptionally clean and uniform, but it's easy to back up a single spreadsheet once a week.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is pretty straightforward to do.

Normally Stackoveerflow won't write your code for you, but this will pretty much loop through all the sheets in the current spreadsheet and log the value in whatever cell you choose (In the example it's cell 'E15'):

```
function collectData(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();//Get all the sheets in Spreadsheet
  for ( i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){//Loop through them
    var cell = sheets[i].getRange("E15").getValue();//Get the data in a specific cell. 
    Logger.log(cell);//Log it (Or whatever). 
  }
}
```

What your looking for here is the [.getSheets()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheets()) method, combined with the [.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getRange(String)) and [.getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValue()) methods, then you can pretty much do whatever you want with the data.